# Combine two small Selects in one in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I am using the following nested Selects as part of a larger query.

Is there a way that I can combine both of them in one so that I don't have to run two separate queries?

```
// ...
R.requester,
(
    SELECT      A.Email AS requesterEmail
    FROM        LogTable A
    WHERE       A.NTID = R.requester
    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
),
R.approver,
(
    SELECT      B.Email AS approverEmail
    FROM        LogTable B
    WHERE       B.NTID = R.approver
    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
),
// ...
```

Comment: You can see right here, hope you can help

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47861/how-to-join-two-result-sets-to-query-on-output-came-from-two-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.Email AS requesterEmail,B.Email AS approverEmail
    FROM  LogTable B
JOIN LogTable A
    ON B.NTID = R.approver AND A.NTID = R.requester
    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

Comment: This turned out to be exactly what I needed - works great ! Thanks a lot for that !

Answer (score 1):

If the queries return the same data you could user UNION ALL

```
SELECT      A.Email AS requesterEmail
FROM        LogTable A
WHERE       A.NTID = R.requester
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE

union all

(
   SELECT      B.Email AS approverEmail
   FROM        LogTable B
   WHERE       B.NTID = R.approver
   FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! Unfortunately it turned out that this doesnt work for me as I cant use the FOR lines in this case.

Comment: So you better use the solution from Mihai